# java- hourglass pattern input not working on even numbers

Tags: java

I have these code for printing hourglass for odd numbers. i need both odd and even to work. pls help

```
int nRows = 4;

for(int i=0; i < nRows/2; i++ ) {
    for(int j = nRows - i; j < nRows; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < nRows - 2*i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}


for(int i=0; i < (nRows+1)/2; i++ )
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= nRows/2 - i; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    for(int j = 0; j <= i*2; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

My output is

```
****
 **
  *
 ***
```

and the output should be

```
****  
 **  
 **    
****
```

Comment: Please add some more details... like what is the expected output and what output you are getting...

Comment: Looking at your expected output, you need 2 different cases for `n` when `even` and `n` when `odd`

Answer (score 1):

make some changes in the second for loop and apply same drawing logic

http://ideone.com/U1xJWv

```
int nRows = 14;

for(int i=0; i < nRows/2; i++ ) {
  for(int j = nRows - i; j < nRows; j++) {
     System.out.print(" ");
  }
  for(int j = 0; j < nRows - 2*i; j++) {
     System.out.print("*");
  }
  System.out.println();
}


for(int i=nRows/2 -1; i >=0; i-- )  // based on first half, in reverse order
{
  for(int j = nRows - i; j < nRows; j++) {
     System.out.print(" ");
  }
  for(int j = 0; j < nRows - 2*i; j++) {
     System.out.print("*");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a figure looking like the one below for `n=6`:

```
******
 ****
  **
  **
 ****
******
```

Here is a simple code to solve it:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nRows = 6;

    if(nRows%2==0)
    {
      hourGlassEven(nRows/2);
    }
    else
    {
      hourGlassOdd((nRows/2)+1);
    }
  }
  public static void hourGlassOdd(int nRows)
  {
    int i,j,k,l;

    for(i=0;i<nRows;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<i;j++)
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for(k=0;k<nRows-i;k++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      for(l=0;l<nRows-i-1;l++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

  for(i=0;i<nRows-1;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<nRows-i-2;j++)
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for(k=0;k<i+2;k++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      for(l=0;l<i+1;l++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  public static void hourGlassEven(int nRows)
  {
    int i,j,k,l;

    for(i=0;i<nRows;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<i;j++)
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for(k=0;k<nRows-i;k++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      for(l=0;l<nRows-i;l++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

  for(i=0;i<nRows;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<nRows-i-1;j++)
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for(k=0;k<i+1;k++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      for(l=0;l<i+1;l++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Added your logic for even numbers too!! Have a look

Comment: thanks for helping.. but  the height and the width should be the same as nRows

Comment: @Marke: I have added your logic!! Please have a look

Comment: thanks @User_Targaryen! i have tried the following and its working.

Answer (score 0):

This code will show the hourglass pattern regardless if the `size` is even or odd.

For those whose still looking for a simpler code regarding hourglass challenge. You may use this as reference.

```
public static void hourGlass(int size) {
    // 2 for loops only
    int dimension = (size * 2) - 1, space = 0, stars = size - 1, printed = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++) {
        int actual = space;
        for (int j=dimension; j > 0; j--) {
            if(actual > 0) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                actual--;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("*");
                if(stars==printed) {
                    actual = space;
                    printed = 0;
                } else {
                    actual = 1;
                    printed++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(i <= size-2) { // will pattern spaces and stars from top to middle
            space++;
            stars--;
        }
        else { // will pattern spaces and stars from middle to top
            space--;
            stars++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes